# Is "fill something in/into something" grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs

My old Japanese-English dictionary (Random House, published on 1993) provides example sentences of the verb "fill" as follows:

> - **fill sand into a pail** [=fill a pail with sand] バケツに砂を入れる
> - **fill wine into bottles** ぶどう酒を瓶に詰める.

I can't find this usage on some famous online English dictionaries such as Longman and Collins.  Is this usage of "fill" correct?

Comment: @randomhead Good answer, what's it doing in the comments?

Comment: @the-baby: Good point, answered and expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I (a native AmE speaker) do not recognize this usage and would not call it idiomatic.

We say someone **fills a vessel** [direct object] ***with* a substance** [indirect object]: **Fill a pail with sand**. We can also make it passive, or change the subject of the sentence while keeping the meaning:

- The pail is filled with sand.
- Sand fills the pail.

If you want to keep the substance as the direct object and the vessel as the indirect object, we use the verb *pour* instead: **Pour wine into bottles**. Unlike with "fill," "pour" only works one way:

- [x] The bottles are poured with wine.
- [✓] Wine is poured into the bottles.

"Pour" is used for things that can flow; wine is a liquid and can flow, and grains of sand, in the aggregate, can also exhibit fluid-like properties (it is perfectly fine to "pour sand into a pail"). For objects which do not flow, we must use another verb, like *pack*:

- The suitcase is packed with clothes.
- Clothes are packed into the suitcase.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot read the symbol in "[?] The bottles are poured with wine" either on my PC or my phone, in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @gotube edited. According to my symbols picker it was the [Aegean check mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegean_Numbers_%28Unicode_block%29) `U+10102` and should appear as an "x" symbol.